# WPF-Custom TabItem with Delete Button Binding Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties, tabitem

Hi i' m trying to create a custom TabItem with delete Button,i want to bind my viewmodel command to my custom Dependency Property 'DeleteCommandProperty' . Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

my Custom TabControl :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// TabControl withCustom TabItem
    /// </summary>
    public class MyTabControl:TabControl
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// TabItem override
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
        {
            return new MyTabItem();
        }
    }
```

my Custom TabItem class :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Custom TabItem
    /// </summary>
    public class MyTabItem:TabItem
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Delete Command 
        /// </summary>
        public static DependencyProperty DeleteCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
           "DeleteCommand",typeof(ICommand),typeof(MyTabItem));

        /// <summary>
        /// Delete
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand DeleteCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(DeleteCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DeleteCommandProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

when i bind the DeleteCommand directly like this my Command in my ViewModel is executed

```
 <customControls:MyTabControl>
            <customControls:MyTabItem Header="Test" DeleteCommand="{Binding DeleteStudiengangCommand}" Template="{DynamicResource MyTabItemControlTemplate}"/>
        </customControls:MyTabControl>
```

bu when try to bind the deleteCommand via style like this but it doesn't work :

```
 <Style TargetType="customControls:MyTabItem">
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource MyTabItemControlTemplate}"/>
                        <Setter Property="DeleteCommand" Value="{Binding MyDeleteCommand}"/>
                    </Style>



<customControls:MyTabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" SelectedIndex="0">
                    <customControls:MyTabControl.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Value}" >
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <WrapPanel/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </customControls:MyTabControl.ContentTemplate>
                </customControls:MyTabControl>
```

Comment: Consider reducing this to a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, do not try to bind the `DeleteCommand` in your style, unless it is essential in showing your problem... Instead, assign a static command in your constructor

Comment: I see you edited your question somehow, but it is very far from being **minimal** (you use far to many templates that are unrelated to your problem), far from being **verifiable** (I built a small example with your style based command setter and it worked just fine), far from being **complete** (where is the code for `customControls:MyTabControl`? Also, please don't force me to use Blend) and you don't really explain what is the observed behavior in contrast to the expected behavior, so no **example** is given either.

Comment: I added my TabControl class and try to explained what did'nt work hope someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

I suspect your `DataContext` contains your current item from `MyList` (whatever it is), so the style setter cannot access the `MyDeleteCommand` property as you planned. Look at the visual studio debugger log, whether a binding exception is logged there.

---

*Example that evolved from a working code until it happened to reveal a possible problem explanation.*

It seems you have some difficulties in reducing your example, so the only thing I can offer you based on the information you provide is a small working example with the `Style` and `TemplateBinding` approach which you can use as a base to identify your real problem. *Edit:* The explanation at the end might actually be the answer to your question.

Note you may have to change the namespaces to match with your project setup.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">

    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- Header template -->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTabItemControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyTabItem}">
            <!-- Some text and the command button with template binding -->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Aquamarine" Margin="3">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2"/>
                <Button Content="Delete" Command="{TemplateBinding DeleteCommand}" Margin="2"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <!-- Setting the control template and assigning the command implementation -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyTabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource MyTabItemControlTemplate}"/>
            <Setter Property="DeleteCommand" Value="{Binding MyDeleteCommand}"/>
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="Default Header Text"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <local:MyTabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyTabItemList}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// TabControl withCustom TabItem
/// </summary>
public class MyTabControl : TabControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// TabItem override
    /// </summary>
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new MyTabItem();
    }
}

public class MyTabItem : TabItem
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Delete Command 
    /// </summary>
    public static DependencyProperty DeleteCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
       "DeleteCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyTabItem));

    /// <summary>
    /// Delete
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(DeleteCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DeleteCommandProperty, value); }
    }
}

public class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello WPF", "Message");
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged { add { } remove { } }
}

public class MyContext
{
    public ICommand MyDeleteCommand { get; set; }

    public List<object> MyTabItemList { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var list = new List<object>();
        list.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "Test 1" });
        list.Add(new MyTabItem() { Content = "Test Content 2", Header = "Test Header 2" });
        list.Add(new TabItem() { Content = "Test Content 3", Header = "Test Header 3" });
        this.DataContext = new MyContext()
        {
            MyTabItemList = list,
            MyDeleteCommand = new MyCommand()
        };
    }
}
```

Summary of the example:
You see three different tabs, each with its unique build and appearance:

1. The tab item is created from the `GetContainerForItemOverride` method, the style setter for the `Header` property specifies the text that appears within the header. The `MyDeleteCommand` binding does not work!
2. The tab item is provided as `MyTabItem` with header and content value. The style setter for the `Header` property does not apply, because the property is explicitely set. The style setter for the `DeleteCommand` property binds to the `MyDeleteCommand` property from `MyContext`.
3. The tab item is provided as `TabItem` and because there is no override of `MyTabControl.IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride`, this is accepted as a control item of `MyTabControl`. The whole `MyTabItem` template does not apply.

The debugging output inside visual studio gives a hint about the underlying problem for the first tab item:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MyDeleteCommand' property not found on 'object' ''TextBlock' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=MyDeleteCommand; DataItem='TextBlock' (Name=''); target element is 'MyTabItem' (Name=''); target property is 'DeleteCommand' (type 'ICommand')

The reason is, that the current tab item content becomes the new local `DataContext` in this scenario unlike the second tab item, where the item itself is accepted as the container.

A solution could be to ensure usage of the propper context on the command binding:

Supposed you give some suitable parent element a name `x:Name="_this"`, then you can access the parent `DataContext`.

```
<Setter Property="DeleteCommand" Value="{Binding DataContext.MyDeleteCommand,ElementName=_this}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you specify the DataContext like you said did solve the Problem.